# How add class to labels in radioButtonList yii 1

Tags: yii, radiobuttonlist

I have this code:

```
  <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'my-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$provider,
    'ajaxUpdate'=>true,
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'status'=>array(
            'type'=>'raw',
            'name'=>'status',
            'value'=>"CHtml::radioButtonList('kk','status',array(1=>'',2=>'',3=>''),array(
                'separator'=>' ',
                'container'=>'',
            ))",
            'htmlOptions' =>array(
                'width'=>'30',
                'class'=>'one',
            ),
        ),
    ),
));?>
```

I need add different classes for every label in radiobuttonList.
If I add:

```
'labelOptions'=>array('class'=>'ddd'),
```

This class will add for all labels. and will get this code:

```
<input id="kk_0" type="radio" name="kk" value="1">
<label class="ddd" for="kk_0"></label>
<input id="kk_1" type="radio" name="kk" value="2">
<label class="ddd" for="kk_1"></label>
<input id="kk_2" type="radio" name="kk" value="3">
<label class="ddd" for="kk_2"></label>
```

I want for example 
if($data->user_id ==2) add class ddd2 to for second label and add class ddd to another labels.
How can do it?

```
<input id="kk_0" type="radio" name="kk" value="1">
<label class="ddd" for="kk_0"></label>
<input id="kk_1" type="radio" name="kk" value="2">
<label class="ddd2" for="kk_1"></label>
<input id="kk_2" type="radio" name="kk" value="3">
<label class="ddd" for="kk_2"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
'value'=>'CHtml::radioButtonList("kk","status",array(1=>"",2=>"",3=>""),array(
                "separator"=>"",
                "container"=>"",
                "labelOptions"=>array("class"=>$data->user_id ==2 ? "ddd2" : "ddd"),
            ))'
```

**Note:-** I haven't tested it. But most probably it would work if I have understood your problem clearly.

Comment: It is not work. syntax error. and it will add class dd2 for all labels in row that user_id=2. I need add to row that user_id =2 but add this class to second its label and not all its label.